# Best solution for synching lists of objects between mobile and web server

Tags: iphone, android, java-me, synchronization

I am looking for experience/opinions/learnings from the use of specific methods, file formats (e.g. syncML) and libraries (funambol, others?) for synchronizing lists between multiple mobile devices and a web server?

We'd like to have the ability for a user to edit lists in multiple mobile devices and in the web, and have them synched periodically, handle gracefully conflicts etc.....without reinventing the wheel.

syncML experience, libraries (with an Apache style license) for syncML or others and experiences would be much appreciated.

We are developing on:
  - Java SE (appengine and other platforms) for server - so Java Servlet 2.3
  - J2ME (on Symbian and others)
  - iOS
  - Android

and so want a solution with broad coverage and good libraries on those platforms if possible.

Data
The items in the lists will be products. This maybe as simple as a text name entered by the user, or a structured product description with many fields. We have an XML format defined for this already will will evolve it. Our preference would be to sync a list of these XML fragments.

Conflicts
We still have to define exactly how conflicts are resolved, or if the user can select the behavior - a bit like ActiveSync and other PC solutions. We don't plan to do anything new in this respect.

Details
We expect for each mobile "copy" of the list to store the data in a local datastore, with a date of the last sync with the server and a list of changes sinc. We also expect each item in the list to have a local ID, and a global (server ID) used to help during the sync.

Over-the-wire-format
We prefer to use an XML format for the data transmission during the sync, that has one or a number of lists, and the items inside each list as elements, with the IDs of each as attributes of the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One idea that is probably too simple is using the same method as SVN or CVS.**

1. First, a device extracts the data (checkout).
2. Upon sync, it would do update
3. if you got any conflicts, ask the user which version it prefers (I'd give the options to choose one of the two, create a new one or consider them two different items)
4. after solving conflicts, commit the current state

**Things to think about:**

1. each item should match to a file (better for complex data) or all items (belonging to the same user) should be placed in the same file?
2. using item's id could make things easier to avoid false-conflicts between items with similar contents
3. you probably should convert any item that you exchange to a xml file (or similar) so the versions can be tracked easier
4. this doesn't mean that you need to send xml back and forth. You can convert xml to the format you wish (url encoded parameters to xml, for example)
5. using a strict format for the files under revision control will make things easier to sync

**Explaining my last point:**

Don't encode url parameters in the order they arrive, but choose some logical order. For example, "a=111&b=222" and "b=222&a=111" should be stored with the same text. Be sure that the same data will always have the same representation even if you receive it in a different format.

These were just my initial thoughts...

Comment: Thanks for interest, here are answers:

Comment: Thanks guys, here are a few answers, one per comment due to the limit on comment size:

Data -
The items in the lists will be products. This maybe as simple as a text name entered by the user, or a structured product description with many fields. We have an XML format defined for this already will will evolve it. Our preference would be to sync a list of these XML fragments.

Comment: Conflicts - 
We still have to define exactly how conflicts are resolved, or if the user can select the behavior - a bit like ActiveSync and other PC solutions.

Will that affect what libraries or data descriptions you would recommend?

Comment: Details - 
We expect for each mobile "copy" of the list to store the data in a local datastore, with a date of the last sync with the server and a list of changes since then.

We also expect each item in the list to have a local ID, and a global (server ID) used to help during the sync.

Comment: Over-the-wire-format -
We prefer to use an XML format for the data transmission during the sync, that has one or a number of lists, and the items inside each list as elements, with the IDs of each as attributes of the elements.

Most of those points are pretty generic.

I'm looking more for specific experiences implementing on server (Java servlets) and multiple mobile platforms (J2ME, Android, iOS), with specific libraries used, etc.

Comment: You could have edited your own question and updated it with new info :)

Comment: "Will that affect what libraries or data descriptions you would recommend" Not really no. And there's nothing "magic" about what you want to do, just make decisions about what will happen when there's different kinds of conflicts and start implementing those decisions :) You could add some kind of version control (keep a history of each item in the XML, even deleted ones) to be able to "roll back" if a conflict resolved in a faulty manner.

Comment: I am very interested in experience/opinions/learnings from the use of specific methods, file formats and libraries on the mentioned OS: Java Servlet for server, Android, iOS and J2ME for clients.....

Answer (score 0):

What are the objects in the list? What kind of data?

How do you want conflicts to be handled? For instance if an object is deleted on device A, synced to server (so the object is deleted on server too), but device B meanwhile edits that object and then syncs. Should the object be re-added? Should it be deleted on device B?